# When import leads from excel to salesforce all leads last modified date changed

Tags: trigger, leads, date

I'm using data loader to import leads from Excel to Salesforce, when the import finished, I sort leads dependent on last modified date = Today. I got all leads, I checked their last modified date and I see all records updated. even the excel didn't include the full list of inserted leads already on Salesforce.

I've a trigger on lead before insert or update to check the company field if it empty to fill it with default value.

```
trigger CheckCompany on Lead (before insert, before update) {
for(lead l : Trigger.new)
{
    if(l.Company==null)
    {
        l.Company='N/A';
    }
}
}
```

is this trigger may do that change !? why last modified date changed for all?

Comment: so, for argument's sake, your database had 1000 leads inserted before today and you used dataloader to import 50 new leads.  When you queried the database after the import, you discovered that all 1050 leads had `lastmodifiedDate = today`. Is this correct?

Comment: yes exactly @crop1645

Comment: (1) is there some batch job that updates Leads? (2) do you have a marketing automation system that syncs to SFDC Leads?  You can see who was the `lastModifiedBy` to gain insight into where the updates are coming from